# Orange Peeling Problem

Tags: general-topology

Given any sphere, in this case, the most suitable sphere would be an orange, could you "peel" of an orange such that when it's fully peeled, the orange peel is a genus-1 loop? Is there any conjectures or theories on this type of subject?

If using any references, please post them at the bottom.

Comment: Give the orange a coordinate system like the earth, and make two cuts in the peel: One is half of a great circle from the equator along the 0° meridian to the north pole an down to the equator along the 180° meridian. The othe goes from the equator to the south pole and back up to the equator along the 90° meridians. Does the resulting peel satisfy what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the liberty of implementing Henning Makholm's suggestion. (TL;DR: The answer is "yes.")

[image: So it begins.]

[image: The cuts.]

[image: Peeling.]

[image: Orange + annulus]

Comment: Is it possible to do this along on continuous cut?

Comment: No because of the Jordan curve theorem.